# How to print an element of a linked list in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, linked-list, nodes

For example, say I have

```
node = {}
node['data'] = ['hi', '8']

newNode = {}
newNode['data'] = ['hello', '6']
```

and I want to compare the numbers 6 and 8 in node and newNode

if I try doing

```
print(node[1])
```

because the numbers are in position 1 of the lists I get an error that says:

> KeyError: 1

Comment: `print(node['data'][1])`

Answer (score 2):

you can compare them as:

```
node["data"][1] == newNode["data"][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

By printing `node[1]`, you're actually searching for a key named `1` inside your node dictionary. Instead, since you named it 'data', use `node['data'][1]`. `node['data']` refers to `['hi', '8']`. The following prints True of False for if 8 and 6 is the same.

```
node = {}
node['data'] = ['hi', '8']
# you can also create the dictionary by doing this:
# node = {'data' :  ['hi', '8']}
# or
# node = dict{'data' =  ['hi', '8']}

newNode = {}
newNode['data'] = ['hello', '6']

# so to compare:

print(node['data'][1]==newNode['data'][1])
```